# Idiomatic way to deploy a shell script on unix

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, deployment

I'm writing a small script to manage my installed `JDK` on a `linux` machine, say for example that the name of the ***script/function*** is `usejdk`.

I come with to ways :

1. `usejdk` is a `bash` function in shell script sourced the file in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`.
2. use `usejdk` as the name of the shell script and add it to the `~/bin`directory which is the `PATH`.

What is the idiomatic way to deploy a shell script on a `unix` machine between the two ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are creating something for other people to use, a self-contained script they can put in their `PATH` and replace with new versions as needed is far easier, better, and maintainable than a function that will require them editing their startup files.